# How to monitor internet connectivity using infinite while loop Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, except

I am using an infinite while loop to perform specific function if internet is available. And to print an statement if internet is not available. Following is the code.

```
import requests,time
while True:
    print("HI")
    try:
        requests.get('https://www.google.com/').status_code
        print('online')
    except:
        print('offline')
```

The code works on first run whether internet is running or not. But once internet gets disconnected it get stuck. Nothing prints. any idea?

And is using infinite while loop a good solution  for this task ?

Comment: The "getting stuck" is probably a timeout, which are set quite long by default. A better check for online-ness is to use ping. The infinite loop is fine, but make sure you add some code to be able to stop it. If this runs in a thread in your application, the application might never exit.

Comment: [Alternative approach - query the network interface](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+get+bytes+sent+and+received+from+network+interface+site%3Astackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be experiencing a TIMEOUT. I.E. when INTERNET is disconnected your request gets stuck. You might try adding a timeout to your request like this:

```
import requests, time

while True:
    print("HI")
    try:
        requests.get('https://www.google.com/', timeout=5).status_code
        print('online')
    except:
        print('offline')
    # do consider adding a sleep here
    time.sleep(2.5)
```